# Python: basic Loop

Tags: python

I know how to do in javascript:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
```

But how to do in Python? Codes:

```py
for i in range(1,3):
    print(i)
```

Result:

```
1
2
```

I can print the result 1 & 2 but the values are wrong when I put `i` into a calculation loop. The values of `i` are forever `2`. Here are the codes:

```py
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
g = data.loc[1:12 , 'close']
for i in range(1,3):
    a = i-g
```

What I want to do is `a = 1-g`& `a = 2-g`when the range is`range(1,3)`

Any ideas?Any help would would be appreciated.

Comment: How about reading `help(range)` before posting questions about its behavior?

Comment: Python's [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) is end-exclusive. `range(a, b)` is analogous to `for (var i = a; i < b; ++i)`.

Comment: You are doing the things you want, you first assign `a = 1-g`, then do `a = 2-g`. There's only one `a` variable though, so you can't see the results of the first calculation after the loop ends. Either do something with it inside the loop, or do something different in the first place (like appending to a `list` rather than assigning to `a`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the "a" variable outside the loop, it will only have the last value assigned to "a", in this case will be 2.

Make sure you use it inside the loop:

```
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
g = data.loc[1:12 , 'close']
for i in range(1,3):
    a = i-g
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The upper bound of the range() function is exclusive.

So this:

```
 for i in range(1,3):
     ...
```

translates to:

```
 var i;
 for (i=1;i<3;i++) {
     ...
 }
```

to obtain the equivalent of `(i=1;i<=3;i++)` you need to add 1 to the upper bound:

```
 for i in range(1,4):
     ...
```